# Get title attribute from galleries

Tags: php, theme-development, gallery

I managed to get all the images of a gallery from another page using [`get_post_gallery()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery) and I entered a description for each of them in the edit gallery window.

I tried using [`get_image_tag()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_image_tag) to get the attributes from all images including the title. The thing is that it shows all the attributes while I only want the title attribute.

Also, it always show "1" in each title attribute.

My php code:

```
$gallery = get_post_gallery(7, false );
$imageIds = explode(',', $gallery['ids']);

// THE VALUES ARE HIGH TO AVOID THE EMPTY OUTPUT THAT OCCUR FOR SOME REASON
$randIds = array_rand($imageIds, 20);
for($i = 15; $i < 20; $i++)
{
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($randIds[$i], 'large');
    $line = '<li><img src="';
    $line .= $image[0];
    $line .= '" title="';
    //$line .= 
    $line .= '"/></li>';
    echo $line;
    echo "GET_IMAGE_TAG";
    echo get_image_tag($randIds[$i], false, true, false);
}
```

And here is the HTML output I have for each for one iteration:

```
<li><img src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/PA107885-768x1024.jpg" title=""/></li>
GET_IMAGE_TAG
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/PA107885-225x300.jpg" alt="" title="1" width="225" height="300" class="align size-medium wp-image-32" />
```

How can I only get the title attribute without having to scrap all my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress actually uses a Built-in Post Type for Attachments ( called `attachment` ) so you can use some of the same functions like [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) which is what you're looking for. Though, I did take some liberties by modifying your code below, using a `foreach` instead of a `for` loop:

```
$gallery = get_post_gallery( 7, false );    // Attempt to get Post Gallery

if( ! empty( $gallery ) ) {                 // IF Gallery Exists, proceed
    $imageIds = explode( ',', $gallery['ids'] );    // Get an array of Gallery IDs
    $randIds  = array_rand( $imageIds, 20 );        // Randomize array

    foreach( $randIds as $imageId ) {               // Foreach instead of For, just easier
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageId, 'large' );
        echo '<li><img src="' . $image[0] . '" title="' . get_the_title( $imageId ) . '" /></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that get_the_title() worked too with images. I used a for loop instead of a foreach because for some reason I get blank images at the beginning of the array, so I just skip them in the code.